# Laravel 5 Eloquent Model Object in AngularJS Controller

Tags: php, angularjs, eloquent, laravel-5

I am fairly new to AngularJS and I am working a new project with Laravel 5 and AngularJS.

So basically, I am trying to update the standings depending on some filters.

Here is how I call my api:

```
$http.post('/api/standings', {
        category: $scope.current_category.id,
        division: $scope.current_division.id,
        gender: $scope.current_gender.slice(0,1),
        season: $scope.current_season.id
    }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        var standings_array = [];
        var stats_array = [];

        angular.forEach(data, function(value,key){
            standings_array[key] = value[0];
            stats_array[key] = value[1];
        });

        $scope.standings = standings_array;
        $scope.team_stats = stats_array;
    });
```

And this is how I return the array:

```
 $teams_array[] = array($team,$stats);
 return $teams_array
```

And my view:

```
  <tr ng-repeat='team in standings'>
        <td><% $index+1 %></td>
        <td><% team.name %></td>
        <td><% team_stats[$index].games_played %></td>
        <td><% team_stats[$index].points %></td>
        <td><% team_stats[$index].win_pct %></td>
  </tr>
```

Everything is fine, except for the win_pct, as it's a model accessor:

```
public function getWinPctAttribute()
{
    $pct = Utils::calculatePercentage($this->points,$this->games_played*3);
    $pct = number_format($pct, 2);

    return $pct;
}
```

But the win_pct is returning nothing... Is there a way for me to access that value?

Thanks,
Ara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `protected $appends = ['win_pct'];` in your Model. Check Eloquent section from Laravel 5 Documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent last paragraph.